# Trocar classe de menu

Tags: jquery

Bom dia. Estou com o seguinte menu:

```
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="?type=0">Ranking PvP</a></li>
<li><a href="?type=2">Ranking Clãs</a></li>
<li><a href="?type=1">Ranking Guilds</a></li>
</ul>
```

Onde a ´class="active"´ define uma coloração diferente para qual aba está aberta. Gostaria que ao usuário escolhesse o Ranking de Clãs por exemplo, trocasse a class do menu pvp para nenhuma e a de clãs para active.
Tentei da seguinte forma mas não obtive sucesso:

```
<script>
$("#li2").click(function(){
$("li1").removeClass("active");
$("li2").addClass("active");
});
</script>
<ul>
<li id="l1" class="active"><a href="?type=0">Ranking PvP</a></li>
<li id="l2"><a href="?type=2">Ranking Clãs</a></li>
<li id="l3"><a href="?type=1">Ranking Guilds</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

de uma forma mais simples, basta você colocar no evento do click ou de qualquer outro que você deseja para remover todas as classes `active` da ul e colocar apenas no `this`  atual que é exatamente aonde você clicou, veja um exemplo : https://jsfiddle.net/acqndz4j/

Comment: Perfeito! era isso mesmo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você não especificou o seletor para o id do elemento, veja a [documentação aqui](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

```
$("#li1").removeClass("active");
$("#li2").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Erro bobo mesmo rsrs. Porém mesmo corrigindo não funcionou :/

Comment: Ao redirecionar a página para o link do item clicado, esta recarregando o valor inicial. Removea os `href` e verifique se a falha persiste. @Guilherme